# Filter with complex key not work (using startkey and endkey)

Tags: view, couchdb

I create a view with Map function:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.market == "m_warehouse") {
        emit([doc.logTime,doc.dbName,doc.tableName], 1);
    }
}
```

---

I want to filter the data with multi-keys:

```
_design/select_data/_view/new-view/?limit=10&skip=0&include_docs=false&reduce=false&descending=true&startkey=["2018-06-19T09:16:47,527","stage"]&endkey=["2018-06-19T09:16:43,717","stage"]
```

but I still got:

```
{
"total_rows": 248133,
"offset": 248129,
"rows": [
    {
        "id": "01CGBPYVXVD88FPDVR3NP50VJW",
        "key": [
            "2018-06-19T09:16:47,527",
            "ods",
            "o_ad_dsp_pvlog_realtime"
        ],
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "01CGBQ6JMEBR8KBMB8T7Q7CZY3",
        "key": [
            "2018-06-19T09:16:44,824",
            "stage",
            "s_ad_ztc_realpv_base_indirect"
        ],
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "01CGBQ4BKT8S2VDMT2RGH1FQ71",
        "key": [
            "2018-06-19T09:16:44,707",
            "stage",
            "s_ad_ztc_realpv_base_indirect"
        ],
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "01CGBQ18CBHQX3F28649YH66B9",
        "key": [
            "2018-06-19T09:16:43,717",
            "stage",
            "s_ad_ztc_realpv_base_indirect"
        ],
        "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

the key `"ods"` should not in the results.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is *not* multi-key .. ist start and endkey. 
if you want to have results by dbname in a special time range.. you need to change the emit to [doc.dbName,doc.logTime,doc.tableName]

then you query startkey=["stage","2018-06-19T09:16:43,717"]&endkey=["stage","2018-06-19T09:16:47,527"]

(btw. are you sure that your timestamp is in the right order ? In your example the second TS is larger than the first..)

Answer (score 0):

As you have chosen a full date/time stamp as the first level of your key, down to millisecond precision, there are unlikely to be any repeating values in the first level of your compound key. If you indexed just the date, say, as the first key, your date would be grouped by date, dbame and table name in a more predictable way

e.g.

```
["2018-06-19","ods","o_ad_dsp_pvlog_realtime"]
["2018-06-19","stage","s_ad_ztc_realpv_base_indirect"]
["2018-06-19",stage","s_ad_ztc_realpv_base_indirect"
["2018-06-19","stage","s_ad_ztc_realpv_base_indirect"
```

With this key structure, the hierarchical grouping of keys works in your favour i.e. all the data from "2018-06-19" is together in the index, with all the data matching ["2018-06-19","stage"] adjacent to each other.

If you need to get to millisecond precision, you could index the data as follows:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.market == "m_warehouse") {
        emit([doc.dbName,doc.logTime], 1);
    }
}
```

This would create index organised by `dbName`, but with a secondary sort on time. You can then extract the data for specified `dbName` between two timestamps.